# mod_wsgi/python sys.path.exend problems

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm working on a mod_wsgi script.. at the beginning is:

```
sys.path.extend(map(os.path.abspath, ['/media/server/www/webroot/']))
```

But I've noticed, that every time I update the script the sys.path var keeps growing with duplicates of this extension:

```
['/usr/lib64/python25.zip'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5/plat-linux2'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5/lib-tk'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5/lib-dynload'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/Numeric'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0'
'/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/scim-0.1'
'/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages'
'/media/server/www/webroot'
'/media/server/www/webroot'
'/media/server/www/webroot'
'/media/server/www/webroot']
```

It resets every time I restart apache..  is there any way to make sure this doesn't happen? I want the module path to be loaded only once..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to worry about checking or using abspath yourself. Use the ‘site’ module's built-in [addsitedir](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.addsitedir) function. It will take care of these issues and others (eg. pth files) automatically:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/media/server/www/webroot/')
```

(This function is only documented in Python 2.6, but it has pretty much always existed.)

Answer (score 3):

One fairly simple way to do this is to check to see if the path has already been extended before extending it::

```
path_extension = map(os.path.abspath,['/media/server/www/webroot/']) 
if path_extension[0] not in sys.path:
    sys.path.extend(path_extension)
```

This has the disadvantage, however, of always scanning through most of `sys.path` when checking to see if it's been extended.  A faster, though more complex, version is below::

```
path_extension = map(os.path.abspath,['/media/server/www/webroot/']) 
if path_extension[-1] not in reversed(sys.path):
    sys.path.extend(path_extension)
```

A better solution, however, is probably to either add the path extensions to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or put a `.pth` file into your `site-packages` directory:

http://docs.python.org/install/index.html

Comment: +1 .pth files are awesome.  So are environment variables set from apache config.

Answer (score 2):

The mod_wsgi [documentation on code reloading](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode) covers this.